# How to dismiss and present a custom popup (UIViewController) using protocols - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have a single view application. I press a button and a custom popup (UIViewController) appears (Presentation: Over Current Context).  I also have a second custom popup (UIViewController) that appears (Presentation: Over Current Context) if i press a button on the first popup - which is dismissed and brings up the second popup immediately after.  My problem is the following: I am not able to dismiss the second popup and present the first popup immediately from a button on the second popup.  I have being using protocol/ delegates to get the first popup appearing, but not able to get the second popup dismissed and bring back the first popup.  I have commented where in which line i get the error.

```
class HomePage: UIViewController, popUpDismissedDelegate, CreateHashTagDelegate{

    @IBAction func showFirtPopUp(_ sender: Any) {
        let firstPopUpVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
        "firstPopUp") as! FirstPopUp
         firstPopUpVC.delegate = self
         present(firstPopUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // CUSTOM PROTOCOL DELEGATE FUNCTION
    func popUpDimissed() {

    // PRESENT SECOND POPUP
    let secondPopUpVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondPopUp") as! SecondPopUp
    present(secondPopUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // PRESENT FIRST POPUP
    func popUpCreateHTagDismissed() {
        let firstPopUpVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstPopUp") as! FirstPopUp
    present(firstPopUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        let secondPopUpVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "createTag") as! SecondPopUp
        secondPopUpVC.createHTagDelegate = self
    }

}


protocol popUpDismissedDelegate {
    func popUpDimissed()

class FirstPopUp: UIViewController{

    var delegate: popUpDismissedDelegate!

    // DISMISS FIRST POPUP AND PRESENT SECOND POPUP ON TOP OF THE HOMEPAGE
    @IBAction func showFirtPopUp(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.delegate.popUpDimissed() // ** 2nd iteration
    }

}



protocol CreateHashTagDelegate {
    func popUpCreateHTagDismissed()
}

class SecondPopUp: UIViewController{

    var createHTagDelegate: CreateHashTagDelegate!

    // DISMISS SECOND POPUP AND PRESENT FIRST POPUP
    @IBAction func showFirstPopUp(_ sender: Any) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

        self.createHTagDelegate.popUpCreateHTagDismissed() // I GET THE ERROR HERE 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: A delegate should never be an implicitly unwrapped optional. It should be an optional (? rather than !). Changing this will prevent the crash, but it won't fix your problem because the delegate will still be nil.  You need to assign a value to the delegate property

Comment: @Paulw11 taking into consideration what you said, also, i wasn't sure where to assign the delegate for 'SecondPopUp' so i placed it within the HomePage 'viewDidLoad'.  is that ok do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate here

```
func popUpDimissed() {
   let secondPopUpVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondPopUp") as! SecondPopUp
   secondPopUpVC.createHTagDelegate = self
   present(secondPopUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

BTW this code inside `viewDidLoad`

```
let secondPopUpVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "createTag") as! SecondPopUp
secondPopUpVC.createHTagDelegate = self
```

is useless

**Edit:**

You have to do the same inside

```
func popUpCreateHTagDismissed() {
    let firstPopUpVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstPopUp") as! FirstPopUp
    firstPopUpVC.popUpDismissedDelegate = self 
    present(firstPopUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure where to set the delegate so I placed it in 'viewDidLoad'.  So where exactly do I set the delegate based on your answer above?

Comment: copy **popUpDimissed** method as in answer and clear all code inside **viewDidLoad** , also you don't have to create a dismiss protocol for every class , only one is sufficient to use inside all the app ,  also **viewDidLoad** won't be called when you dismiss a modal vc

Comment: you are an IOS ninja. many thanks! was banging by head on this problem for hours.

Comment: you missed this **firstPopUpVC.popUpDismissedDelegate = self** the key point of the answer , see edit

Comment: Sh_Khan - your solution works the first time round when I dismiss the second popup and re-present the first popup.  However, if i try straight after to dismiss the first popup and re-present the second popup, the app crashes at the line indicated above (** 2nd iteration).  I can make the delegates optional - this will solve the crash but does not re-present the second popup again.  I hope this makes sense

Comment: @dean copy the edited method inside **Edit:** and try